# How to have a different instance of the handler/processor for each client in Thrift?

Tags: java, thrift

I know that the handler run in a different server thread for each client, but how can I have one instance of the handler for each client.

I'm writing my server in Java.

EDIT: I just figured it out. I have to provide my own implementation of the TProcessorFactory. The default implementation returns a singleton. http://people.apache.org/~jfarrell/thrift/0.6.1/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/TProcessorFactory.html

Comment: You need to pass the handler class to Thrift?